# Clang AST Matchers: matching on nestedNamespaces

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-ast-matchers

Given a class with a private member of a different namespace

```
namespace Test { namespace Cfg {
class ExampleApi {
public:
    ExampleApi() = default;
    int someVar;
};
}}

class Example {
public:
    Example() = default;
private:
   Test::Cfg::ExampleApi _cfgApi;
};
```

I'm trying to match on the nested namespace Cfg for a cxxConstructorExpr as my final goal is to read some variable names from the ExampleApi class

I can match `_cfgApi` by doing something like:

```
cxxConstructExpr(hasType(asString("Test::Cfg::ExampleApi")))
```

But this isn't good enough since the code base auto generates classes under `Test::Cfg::*Api` and I haven't found usage of wild cards predicates.

I tried doing doing something with:

```
nestedNameSpecificierLoc(hasPrefix(loc(specifiesNamespace(hasName("Test")))))
```

which matches the namespace but not the nested namespace. I think it might be too much noise to go through in post-processing after the match happens.

I was playing with the `hasParent` matcher but have had no luck so far.

So my question is: How do i match on the nested namespace for a class initialization.